NextUI Tooltip not rendering - Warning: Function components cannot be given refs
I am using NextUI in a Next.js project however the Tooltip component will not render to the screen. I get the following error in the console:
Warning: Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?

And here is my code:
import { Tooltip } from "@nextui-org/tooltip";
import { AiOutlineEdit } from "react-icons/ai";

export const SomeComponent = () => {

  return (
    <Tooltip showArrow={true} placement="bottom" content={`${userCanEdit ? 'Rename file' : 'Cannot Rename File'}`}>
      <AiOutlineEdit size={18} />
    </Tooltip>
  );
}

I am not trying to use a ref so I don't understand this error in this context. It might be unrelated but for some reason the props I pass to nextUI components like showArrow and placement do not take effect.
